# Hide id or div from displaform.aspx

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i wanna hide the section : created by and date of creation from my display form page, on SharePoint online

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU2Dl.png)

i've tryed to edit displayform.aspx page with sharepoint designer by adding css code with display: none property and it doesn't work ,
here is the link of my page : /sites/mysite/Forms/DispForm.aspx.

is there any other solution ?

Comment: is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option is you can remove created by and date of creation using jquery code. You need to do is to put below code in CEWP on your list from.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("td[id='onetidinfoblock1']").remove();
      $("td[id='onetidinfoblock2']").remove();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you your code is fine,but the problem is that i'm not able to add content editor webpart to custom DispForm.aspx
How can i do it ?

Comment: If you want to do this for dispform of all lists then you can add this script on master page